# How to open mat date picker in a modal?

Tags: angular, datepicker, material-design, angular-material

i have an angular 4 project requirement of opening a mat-date picker in a modal.I ve tried lot of ways of doing it and searched on web,but failed.
Is there any appropriate way to do it ?or any other nice date-picker which opens in a modal or pop up something ?

```
<mat-form-field>
     <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
     <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
     <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: modal using material or bootstarp.?

Comment: what have you tried? Can you please share your CSS code etc. tried. And how are you failing? I guess what you are asking can be done by simply adding few css codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `touchUi` input of `MatDatepicker` for a touch UI which is meant for mobile users. (You can treat it as a modal though)

```html
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker touchUi></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```